# Laravel Job fails during execution: method_exists()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, backend, jobs

We are running on Laravel 6 and we have got the following problem. A job we execute, that counts the number of impressions and clics of certain images triggers the following error, due to a high number of calls to the function:

> method_exists(): The script tried to execute a method or access a
> property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class
> definition "App\Jobs\RegisterHouseLog" of the object you are trying to
> operate on was loaded before unserialize() gets called or provide an
> autoloader to load the class definition

We already increased the number of tries so it executes after sometime, so it's not the actual problem, but it sends an error to our error logs (Slack Channel) and causes a lot of "spam".

I was trying to fix the above error but I wasn't able to fix it, so at least I tried to "mute" the notification through an "failed job exception" but still to it fails.

The best would be to resolve the actual problem, the second best would be to mute it.
Anyone could help?

The Job:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\HouseLog;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Exception;

class RegisterHouseLog implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $tries = 20;

    public $house_id;
    public $user_id;
    public $date;
    public $type;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($house_id,$user_id,$type, $date)
    {
        $this->house_id = $house_id;
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->date = $date;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $log = new HouseLog();
        $log->user_id = $this->user_id;
        $log->house_id = $this->house_id;
        $log->type = $this->type;
        $log->date = $this->date;
        $log->save();
    }

    public function failed(Exception $exception)
    {
        Log::critical('Failed Register House');
    }
}
```

And the call:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\api;

use App\HouseLog;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Jobs\RegisterHouseLog;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class HouseLogController extends Controller
{
    public function registerLog(Request $request)
    {
            $date = Carbon::now();
            RegisterHouseLog::dispatch($request->house_id, $request->user_id, $request->type, $date);
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score -2):

This error is likely due to the job dispatcher not being able to resolve `\App\Jobs\RegisterHouseLog` when it pulls from the job queue to kick off a job.

Try clearing the class loader cache:

```
artisan cache:clear
```

Also try restarting your job dispatcher process.

```
artisan queue:restart
```

It may not be the best solution, but you could also fix this by removing `implements ShouldQueue` from your job class definition; it would make the job kick off right away without going through the queue.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! I am going to try it, to see if it works. 
The second solution with ShouldQueue wouldn't cause a slowing down the page? Sorry for the stupid questions, it's just that I thought the jobs are exactly to avoid the direct execution.